# How to solve edit and delete issue for gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Error is below:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
  
 For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the DataBinding of the GridView in a IsPostBack check.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = loadDataFromSomewhere;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This should fix the error as long as you are not adding data to DropDowns or RadioButtonLists with jQuery or something similar when editing an item.

Comment: i am using sql data source to configure my gridview

Comment: i am configuring my sql data source with a data table then configure gridview with it w